# how to apply the url encoder for the usersName in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below code output of usersName is [user3, user1, user2] in this output after , symbol it's giving space.
For that How to apply the urlencoder for usersName.

Final output I want like this usersName=[user3,user1,user2]

**java**

```
public String CreateGroup(String groupname,String username,
            ArrayList<FriendInfo> result) throws UnsupportedEncodingException  {

         List<String> usersName = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) { 
            usersName.add(result.get(i).userName); 

            }
                String params = "groupname="+ URLEncoder.encode(groupname,"UTF-8") +
                        "&username="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.username,"UTF-8") +
                        "&password="+ URLEncoder.encode(this.password,"UTF-8") +
                        "&friendUserName=" +usersName+      
                        "&action="  + URLEncoder.encode("CreateGroup","UTF-8")+
                        "&";

            Log.i("PARAMS", params);
            return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);      


    }
```

Comment: `String.trim()`? Or `String.replace(" ","")`

Comment: how to apply for the  "&friendUserName=" +usersName+  here

Comment: Are you really trying to add a list to a string?

Comment: it's giving error replace() method

Comment: That's because it is a list and not a string. You have to use replace on your `result.get(i).userName` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing arguments through http you need to encode the spaces by replacing them with "+" or "%20".

Your for should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) { 
  usersName.add(result.get(i).userName.replace(" ","+")); 
}
```

If you remove the spaces like the other anwser sugested your usernames would have incorrect information like "JohnSmith" instead of "John Smith"

Finaly since you're using your list you should do this:

```
"&friendUserName=" +usersName.toString().replace(" ","+")
```

Comment: Still it's giving space

Comment: Why are you adding a list to the "friendUserName"? Shouldn't it be just one username? And if you're sending more than one shouldn't they be concatenated?

Comment: which one i want to add

Comment: [user3,%20user1,%20user11] this output

Comment: You're asking me? You the one that should know what you're doing. And in that output I see no space..... I see commas... but no spaces.

Comment: it's giving [user3, user1, user11] like this

Comment: @user1 see my edit. It will give something like `[user3,+user1,+user11]`. You can call `replace(", ","+")` if you don't want to see that comma

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
usersName.add(result.get(i).userName);
```

to this:

```
usersName.add(result.get(i).userName.replaceAll("\\s",""));
```

This is under the assumption that your userName is the one that includes the whitespace and not the userNames List.

Comment: [user3,%20user1,%20user11] output giving like this